# Python script for URL split

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to python,learning the basics.

**My Query :**
I have multiple pages accessed as a request from a log file like the below,

```
"GET /img/home/search-user-ico.jpg HTTP/1.1"  
"GET /SpellCheck/am.tlx HTTP/1.1"
"GET /img/plan-comp-nav.jpg HTTP/1.1" 
"GET /ie6.css HTTP/1.1"
"GET /img/portlet/portlet-content-bg.jpg HTTP/1.1"
"GET /SpellCheck/am100k2.clx HTTP/1.1" 
"GET /SpellCheck/am.tlx HTTP/1.1"
```

My question is i want only the file part from the page,
For example,
Let us consider `"GET /img/home/search-user-ico.jpg HTTP/1.1" ,"GET /ie6.css HTTP/1.1"` as a page then from the above i want to split **`search-user-ico.jpg HTTP`**, **`ie6.css HTTP`**.

so experts please help me in writing the python script for the above to split.

Comment: The HTTP part that follows both filenames is not part of the actual filename, are you sure you want to match that?

Comment: So you want "HTTP" in the output string but not the HTTP version?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you don't have spaces in the filenames and that you don't want "HTTP" at the end.

You can split the line by space.

```
parts = line.split(" ")
```

and then use the `os` module to get the filename from the path.

```
filename = os.path.basename(parts[1])
```

For example.

```
>>> line = "GET /img/home/search-user-ico.jpg HTTP/1.1"
>>> parts = line.split(" ")
>>> parts[1]
'/img/home/search-user-ico.jpg'
>>> os.path.basename(parts[1])
'search-user-ico.jpg'
```

Comment: As a one-liner, assuming ``entries`` is a list/tuple of the entries: ``filenames = [os.path.basename(entry.split()[1]) for entry in entries]``

Comment: +1. @Jothi in case you've not seen it before @Blair has modified my code into a "List Comprehension" a very neat feature of Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [
"GET /img/home/search-user-ico.jpg HTTP/1.1",
"GET /SpellCheck/am.tlx HTTP/1.1",
"GET /img/plan-comp-nav.jpg HTTP/1.1" ,
"GET /ie6.css HTTP/1.1",
"GET /img/portlet/portlet-content-bg.jpg HTTP/1.1",
"GET /SpellCheck/am100k2.clx HTTP/1.1" ,
"GET /SpellCheck/am.tlx HTTP/1.1" 
]

for url in data:
    print url.split(' ')[1].split('/')[-2]
```

Comment: This will break in all kinds of edge cases. Also, it matches the second to last part of the middle string, not the last part.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
"GET /img/home/search-user-ico.jpg HTTP/1.1",
"GET /SpellCheck/am.tlx HTTP/1.1",
"GET /img/plan-comp-nav.jpg HTTP/1.1" ,
"GET /ie6.css HTTP/1.1",
"GET /img/portlet/portlet-content-bg.jpg HTTP/1.1",
"GET /SpellCheck/am100k2.clx HTTP/1.1" ,
"GET /SpellCheck/am.tlx HTTP/1.1" 
]

for url in data:
    print url.split(' ')[1].split('/')[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format of your links is similar. Another solution would be:

```
request = "GET /img/home/search-user-ico.jpg HTTP/1.1"
parts = request.split("/")
parts[-2] //returns search-user-ico.jpg HTTP
```